# How to check if a pip package exists in certain given custom index?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I've to check whether a package exists in the given index-url (authenticated) using python script.

For example:

I've to check if package `package-1` exists in index [https://mytestdomain.com/pypi/pypi/simple/](https://mytestdomain.com/)

Is there any method to achieve this?

**What I've tried?**

I've tried the cli method, like configuring `pip.conf` with the above index-url and using `pip download <package_name>`

Comment: I think you can simply check if `https://mytestdomain.com/pypi/pypi/simple/package-1` exists

Comment: PyPI has JSON and Simple APIs: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpypi%5D+API . Other indices must have at least the Simple API.

Comment: @sinoroc yeah but not all indexes are public, we need to authenticate and do follow the same process for this.

Comment: Then I do not understand what the question really is about. I think you should rewrite the question to really highlight what you need help with. What is blocking you? Checking if the URL exists is how pip does it as far as I know (this or the JSON API). I do not know what else you expect from this question...

Comment: @sinoroc Yeah I got it, I found your answer much easier than the other methods, cool.

Comment: @sinoroc Added solution with your suggested approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `subprocess.run` with the [`--no-deps`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-no-deps) and [`--dry-run`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-dry-run) options:

```py
import subprocess, sys

def check_exists(package_name: str, index_url: str = "https://pypi.org/simple") -> bool:
    return not subprocess.run(
        [
            sys.executable,
            "-m",
            "pip",
            "install",
            "--dry-run",
            "--no-deps",
            "--index-url",
            index_url,
            package_namee,
        ],
        capture_output=True,
    ).returncode
```

Comment: Hint: Don't use `python` with `subprocess`, use [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable) for the current `python`.

Comment: @phd any reason for this

Comment: @DilLip_Chowdary For this particular answer it doesn't matter much but you should remember that `python` and `sys.executable` could be different Pythons. Running `python` requires it to be in `$PATH` while `sys.executable` could be anything depending on how the script is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution without pip cli (2x faster than pip cli method).

```py
def check_if_package_exists_in_given_index(package_name_with_version: str, index_url: str) -> bool:
    if "==" in package_name_with_version:
        package_name, version = package_name_with_version.split("==")

        package_url = index_url.strip(
            "/") + f"/{package_name.replace('_', '-')}/{version}/{package_name}-{version}.tar.gz"
    else:
        package_name = package_name_with_version

        package_url = index_url.strip("/") + f"/{package_name.replace('_', '-')}"

    response = requests.get(url=package_url)

    return response.status_code == 200
```